# IBM Worklight 6.2: Error's and warning on startup of Liberty Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security, worklight-runtime

I am setting up the Testing Environment.

**Environment details are,**

1. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2
2. 1.6.0_22 - OpenJDK Runtime Environment
3. Liberty Server 8.5.5.1
4. IBM DB2 V10.1
5. IBM Worklight 6.2 Enterprise

**Procedure followed to install:**

1. IBM Worklight 6.2 Enterprise Installed on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.1 + DB2 V10.1
2. ant -f configuration-liberty-db2.xml admdatabases
3. ant -f configuration-liberty-db2.xml adminstall
4. ant -f configuration-liberty-db2.xml databases
5. ant -f configuration-liberty-db2.xml install

I could see the run time by using Worklight Console `[http://WLServer:9080/worklightconsole]` even preview of the application is also working.

My concern is I am getting huge warning and error's where I am unable to figure out the cause.

**Below are those error and warning from Liberty server log.**

I know its a long data. Hope next time I will share the log in better way.

*[err] 20  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources/worklight/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.*

*[err] 965  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2*

*[err] 1047  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary".*

*[err] 0  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources/worklight/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.*

*[err] 35  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2*

*[err] 189  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10010 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.13.127).*

*[err] 1582  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] 1984  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2*

*[err] 2013  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10010 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.13.127).*

*[err] 1667  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] 1702  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] 2134  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] 2155  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] dataBaseFromDataSource=true*

*[err] dataBaseUrl=jdbc:db2://WLServer:50000/APPCNTR*

*[err] dataBaseDriver=IBM DB2 JDBC Universal Driver Architecture*

*[err] dataBaseDriverVersion=3.63*

*[err] dataBaseProduct=DB2/LINUXX8664*

*[err] dataBaseVersion=SQL10010*

*[err] dataBaseUser=db2inst1*

*[err] 92  appcenterdb-db2  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2*

*[err] 543  appcenterdb-db2  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10010 ,IBM DB2 JDBC Universal Driver Architecture 3.63.123).*

*[err] 20471  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] 20481  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] 21594  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.*

*[err] 16  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2*

*[err] 18  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10010 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.13.127).*

*[err] 88462  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-3] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2*

*[err] 88467  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-3] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10010 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.13.127).*

Please let me know Where and What I have missed.

Answer (score 1):

The warning can be safely ignored --- per http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21605316

Comment: Is there a way to suppress those warning..?